# Content alignment of Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to format my TOC as shown in the sample image. I've been able to remove the dots, but I can't find out to reduce the space between the section name and the page number. By default the page number is right aligned. I'm not sure if this is an important detail, but I'm using Overleaf. Your help is appreciated as I'm still a novice with LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are many example here of customized TOCs.  Also, are you using tocloft or some other package, or just modifying `\l@chapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown how you have altered the ToC. We don't know what you have tried so really don't know what to suggest you do further.

However, the `tocloft` package is the usual answer to problems involving the ToC (and LoF and LoT).

```
[![% tocpageprob.tex  SE 639920

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% set page numbers just after chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
% set page numbers just after section titles
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
% set page number at the right of its box
\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{r}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{Premier}
\subsection{Sub}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Read the `tocloft` manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sorry my question wasn't clear, but you answered it. I wasn't quite sure what to search for in the documentation.